# Sort varchar2 filed with numbers, decimal point and text in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sort a varchar2 field in a oracle table. The values that i am trying to sort are :

```
Firmware( column name)
3.9P7S1
3.10P4S1
```

If i do Order by Firmware desc i get the '3.9P7S1' whereas i am expecting '3.10P4S1'.

Would be great to find some help in solving this problem .

Comment: Obviously the period separator is NOT a "decimal point" - if it were, the results would be correct since 3.9 is greater than 3.10. (3.10 is the same as 3.1, if you regard them simply as decimal numbers, right?)  So, you must separate the two numbers, "3" and "9" or "10" and consider them as unrelated ordering criteria, not as a single decimal number like "3.9" and "3.10". Then: is the pattern always the same, namely an integer, **always** followed by a period, then another integer, and then other characters?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for your explanation, got you.Yes its a firmware version, its always in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. Assuming that all inputs have one or more digits, followed by a period, followed by one or more digits, followed by some other fragment (possibly empty) that does not begin with a digit... Order by the first integer descending, then by the second integer descending, then by the remaining fragment ASCENDING and with nulls first (so for example firmware '3.8' comes before '3.8A'):

```
with
  inputs (firmware) as (
    select '3.9P7S1'  from dual union all
    select '3.10P4S1' from dual union all
    select '3.9PX20K' from dual union all
    select '3.1ST8X2' from dual union all
    select '3.1'      from dual union all
    select '2.9P7S1'  from dual union all
    select '3.9ABC32' from dual
  )
select firmware
from   inputs
order by to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '^\d+')) desc,
         to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '^\d+\.(\d+)', 1, 1, null, 1)) desc,
         regexp_replace(firmware, '\d+\.\d+') asc nulls first
;

FIRMWARE
--------
3.10P4S1
3.9ABC32
3.9P7S1
3.9PX20K
3.1
3.1ST8X2
2.9P7S1
```

Comment: This works , but it only till one or more digits after the decimal point. Say for example i had '3.9P1S3' and '3.9P7S1', based on the above it returns '3.9P1S3'. If the initial number are the same it needs to consider the rest ie. P1S3 or P7S1 to sort. In this example i would want to get - '3.9P7S1'. Thanks

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy - I showed you how to break apart the input string into three parts. I believe what you are saying here is that you want the third part to also be sorted descending. Do you see ASC NULL FIRST after the third sorting rule, in the ORDER BY clause? Change that to DESC to get descending order.

Comment: ah! sorry about that. It does work perfectly after changing the second part to desc. Thanks a ton for the help, really appreciate it bud.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, we need number before any string charater for ordering.

You can use `regexp_substr` as following:

```
Select firmware, 
       regexp_substr(firmware, '[0-9]+(\.)[0-9]+') as num
  from your_table
Order by to_number(regexp_substr(num, '[0-9]+',1,1)) desc, 
     to_number(regexp_substr(num, '[0-9]+',1,2)) desc nulls last
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, this does sorts the first half before the decimal point. I wanted to sort the entire thing. I was able to get this done with the sample you provided. Thanks much appreciate it.